# To use an existing timeout when the bot restarts

Tags: discord.py

How do I resume the existing timeout when I restart the bot?

Is there only one way to save it to another database?
I'm curious how you save it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple JSON file.

```py
@bot.listen()
async def event() 
with open('NameOfFile.json','r') as f:
            example = json.load(f)
       #code
 with open('NameOfFile.json','w') as f:
                json.dump(example_count,f,indent=4)
```

Comment: JSON is not a database

Comment: You can use a json file to store data is what my point was.

Comment: You _can_, but for a Discord bot you should use an _actual_ database instead of a JSON file